# How can I attract attention to recently undeleted, old poorly received questions before they get deleted again by the Community user?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts

More on the topic of salvaging poorly-received questions, once they are undeleted, how can I attract more attention to them so that they will get voted accounting for how well I edited them? How can I do it fast enough that they won't get automatically redeleted again by the Community user?

Comment: Did you edit those posts before are after they got undeleted?

Comment: In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035979/how-do-i-create-gtk2-style-widgets-in-gtk3) you need to do what is adviced in the last comment\; show some code, an attempt maybe and/or how you did that in gtk2. If not done before saturday and good enough to earn you an up vote (or an answer) it will roomba again (it is in the 30-days batch, that runs once a week).

Comment: you could try a bounty, if your question has improved significantly, but reading renes linked question, you should urgently take the So tour and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @rene I edited them after they got undeleted.